# Splitter in Qt5 is invisible

Tags: c++, mingw, qt5

I have been creating a small frame window with a splitter object, using the Qt Designer. What is strange though is, that the splitter is working, so when I move the mouse where it should be, the cursor switches it's shape and I can drag the splitter, but the splitter bar itself is invisible.

Is this a bug from Qt5? I'm using Qt 5.2.1 OpenSource with MingW on Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot of missing splitter]
<sub>(source: [picr.de](http://up.picr.de/17909316nw.jpg))</sub>

**Update**

I created now a bugreport for [this issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38288)

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the handlewidth? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsplitter.html#handleWidth-prop

Comment: Yes, the width is set to 5 which should make it visible.But even setting to ridiculous value of 20 I can see that the space is reserved, but it is not visible.

Comment: I created a bugreport on the Qt site.

Answer (score 2):

I have also invisible splitter (Using Qt 5.3). 
But I am using some complex style sheet which colors it in a way I need and it is visible that way:

```
QSplitter::handle {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Please check the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet.html) how to apply style sheet.